# ¿Cómo usar ordenes comando top?

Tags: shell, unix

Estoy usando el comando de top en la shell y, no sé como funciona las ordenes dentro del comando. Lo que quiero hacer, es poder monitorear un determinado proceso según su PID. He visto en foros, que si pulsas "o" permite el filtrado, pero no he encontrado cómo son las ordenes.

Comment: -1 Mira que es facil ... `man top`. En mi *distro*, está traducido al español y todo :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien comentas si pulsas "o" se activan los filtros.
Eso te mostrará la leyenda:

```
add filter #1 (ignoring case) as: [!]FLD?VAL
```

Lo que te pide es el nombre del filtro seguido de un operador relacional (el signo de mayor, de menor o de igual) y luego el valor.

Entre más uses "o" más filtros agregarás. Para quitar todos los filtros pulsas "="

Ahora bien.

¿Cómo filtro por un proceso en particular?

Supongamos que quiero filtrar por el proceso cuyo PID es 1. 
[image: Todos los procesos]

Agrego un filtro con -o para buscar los PID con valor mayor a 0 y doy Enter.

```
add filter #1 (ignoring case) as: [!]FLD?VAL PID>0
```

[image: Filtrando por mayores a 0]

Luego agrego un filtro con -o para buscar los PID con valor menor a 2 y doy Enter.

```
add filter #2 (ignoring case) as: [!]FLD?VAL PID<2
```

[image: Filtrando por procesos menores a 2]

Lo cual nos devuelve lo esperado:
[image: Resultado con dos filtros]

¿Porque no puse simplemente un filtro con PID=1?
Por que si lo pongo así el comando me muestra todos aquellos procesos cuyo PID tiene el valor 1 en su texto.

```
add filter #1 (ignoring case) as: [!]FLD?VAL PID=1
```

[image: Filtrando por proceso con PID igual a 1]

Lo cual nos arroja:
[image: Resultado al filtrar por PID igual a 1]

Lo cual no es lo esperado.
Espero haberte ayudado.